# Float right appears like a step inside list

Tags: html, css

I am using float right to make two links appear on the right of every list item. But they do not stick to the right side for all the list items, causing it to appear like a step. I have tried a lot of combinations from various answers on SO for about 4 days. Nothing seemed to work.

I asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47475994/float-right-in-list-item-causes-the-elements-to-appear-like-a-step), two days ago on SO, and did not get any response, probably because it had JSF code. So I have stripped down the html generated to the minimal code that replicates this issue.

https://jsfiddle.net/9g5h6687/10/

```css
.labelTitleBox {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline;
}

.layerPanelButton {
  font-size: 18pt !important;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #0092cf !important;
}

.layerPanelButtonWrap {
  width: auto;
  float: right;
  padding-left: 4px;
  padding-right: 4px;
  color: #0092cf !important;
}

.label {
  width: auto;
  display: inline;
  white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<div id="form:layerTree" class="ui-widget-content">
  <ul>
    <li id="form:layerTree:0">
      <span class="label">
    <span class="layerPanelButtonWrap"><a href="#" class="layerPanelButton" title="Show Tools">%</a></span>
        <div class="labelTitleBox">Node 0</div>
      </span>
      <ul class="">
        <li id="form:layerTree:0_0">
          <span class="label">
      <span class="layerPanelButtonWrap"><a href="#" class="layerPanelButton" title="Show Tools">=</a></span>
           <span class="layerPanelButtonWrap"><a href="#" class="layerPanelButton" title="Show Tools">%</a></span>
           <div class="labelTitleBox">Node 0.0</div>
          </span>
        </li>
        <li id="form:layerTree:0_1">
          <span class="label">
      <span class="layerPanelButtonWrap"><a href="#" class="layerPanelButton" title="Show Tools">=</a></span>
           <span class="layerPanelButtonWrap"><a href="#" class="layerPanelButton" title="Show Tools">%</a></span>
           <div class="labelTitleBox">Node 0.1</div>
          </span>
        </li>
        <li id="form:layerTree:0_2">
          <span class="label">
      <span class="layerPanelButtonWrap"><a href="#" class="layerPanelButton" title="Show Tools">=</a></span>
           <span class="layerPanelButtonWrap"><a href="#" class="layerPanelButton" title="Show Tools">%</a></span>
           <div class="labelTitleBox">Node 0.2</div>
          </span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Just clear the floating on the `li` ...

Comment: .label { display: block; overflow:hidden; position: relative; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clear the floats because the font size of the floated items are larger than the line-height of `li` so they stack on each other

```
ul ul {clear:right;}
li:after {display:block; clear:right; content:'';}
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9g5h6687/14/)

Also, nothing to do with the problem but you have invalid html in your answer - `div` is not allowed to be a child element of a `span`

Comment: Thanks, the clear helped. The HTML is generated by prime-faces component, therefore the div in the span. I will fix that too.

Comment: You're welcome, glad to help.  Not sure why you were downvoted, but I have cancelled that out

Answer (score 0):

It is the wrapping element's height that causes the indent of the floating elements.

If you add a height the spans will float right as expected.

```
li {
    height:50pt;
}
```

This will not fix your list completly, but it could point you in the right direction.

https://jsfiddle.net/9g5h6687/13/